# Why do we use npm init command in any new project?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

In my travel in learning **Front End Development** I started with creating simple projects with three files (JavaScript file, HTML file, CSS file).
But now I find that in any project I should create new files with `npm init` command which makes JSON file and a lot of folders like **dist** and others.
The thing that I can't Understand is why I should create this JSON file? The other thing is I find that Gulp is a task runner, but why when I install Sass for example I should type `gulp install gulp-sass` and not `npm install gulp-sass` because npm is the package manager and responsible for installing packages not gulp.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: npm init simply makes package.json, you can make it manually if you know the structure or already have one you can copy and paste, it doesn't create a dist folder or any other folder. You need a package.json file to place your packages in, else how would npm know what packages your project needs.

Comment: I can use packages and tools in my project without npm and making json file?

Comment: kinda, if its just gulp you're using maybe just by installing it globally with `npm i -g `. But if it's a dependency of the project like react, vue,, jquery, etc etc then no. If you `import foo from 'foo'` or `const foo = require('foo')` there won't be a `node_modules` folder for the bundler to pick the code from, so it won't be found. Basically, if you want to use packages, then you need a package.json, there is no reason not to.. also if other people want to build you project, it's easier to say run `npm i` then you got to install this and this and this all globally.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the package.JSON file is the heart of your NPM project. Theres a really good article here on understanding the file: [https://heynode.com/tutorial/what-packagejson/#:~:text=json%20file%20is%20the%20heart,entry%20point%20to%20our%20package](https://heynode.com/tutorial/what-packagejson/#:%7E:text=json%20file%20is%20the%20heart,entry%20point%20to%20our%20package).

It is what allows your NPM project to run, shows any dependencies, has the metadata for it etc.